# ViewPager узнать смещение страницы

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть ViewPager, каким методом можно узнать отклонение от центра страницы?
То есть если страница неподвижно стоит в центре, то отклонение 0. Если начали тащить страницу влево, то отклонение растёт от 0 до 100 к примеру, в другую сторону тащим то отклонение от 0 до -100. Задержали палец на середине, где видно половину обеих страниц, то отклонение 50.
Что то в этом роде нужно, перерыл методы, ничего подобного не нашел.
Судя по документации, это в этом методе:

```
void onPageScrolled (int position, 
                float offset, 
                int offsetPixels)
```

Но вот как из него эти данные вытащить не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onPageScrolled(int,%20float,%20int)), в этом самом onPageScrolled есть positionOffset, принимающий значения от 0 до 1 и position, соответствующий первой видимой странице.

```
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        int selectedPage = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position < selectedPage) {
                onPageScrolled(positionOffset - 1);
            } else {
                onPageScrolled(positionOffset);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            selectedPage = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        public void onPageScrolled(float currentPageOffset) {
            Log.d("TAG", "offset: " + (int) (currentPageOffset * 100));
        }
    });
```

Но нужно понимать, что "текущая" страница изменится, как только вы отпустите ViewPager. Вообще изначальный вариант с positionOffset от 0 до 1 первой видимой страницы кажется удобнее, чем то что вы просите.